# How get code error from request CURL php?

Tags: php, curl

I use code:

```
public function GetPage($url, $post=false, $data=null){ //Function Auth
        $this->refferer = $url;
        curl_setopt($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        if($post == true){
            curl_setopt($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        }
        return curl_exec($this->curl_obj);
    }
```

This function returns false, why? how i can find out the cause?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [curl_error()](http://php.net/curl_error)

```
        print_r(curl_error($this->curl_obj)) ;
        //print_r(curl_getinfo($this->curl_obj)) ;  // for detailed information
```

Based on your comment below. Add these two options to your CURL before execution
**Warning:** This will remove  SSL warnings even if some middle man messes up with your route

```
curl_setopt ($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you. I got error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed. What can you advise me for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details by calling:

```
echo curl_error($this->curl_obj);
```

If you want to return the content, you will need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl_obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If you don't set this, then cURL will echo out the content instead of returning as the return value of your function.